# Optional commands in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, session, unix, terminal

I'm trying to create a session in unix that will allow my to ask a simple question and then ask different questions varying on the answer.
For example if I were to ask 
 'Enter a choice (quit/order)'

if 'quit' is entered then program should close
if 'order' is entered then the program should continue asking further questions.

If you can help that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the shell's `select` command comes in handy. I'm going to assume you're using bash

```
PS3="Enter a choice: "
select answer in Quit Order; do
    case $answer in
        Quit) echo "Thanks for playing."; exit ;;
        Order) 
            # select is like an infinite loop: you need to break out of it
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "Use the numbers to select your answer." ;;
    esac
done
# carry on with the next question
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Lots of choices.."
read -p "What is your choice? " choice

echo "Your choice was $choice"

if [ $choice == "quit" ]
then
echo "Exiting.."; exit 0
fi

if [ $choice == "order" ]
then
echo "Doing some other stuff.."
fi
```